# ViewPager Nested Fragment Not Replacing Correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with 3 fragments. One of the fragments contains a RecyclerView. I click on an item in the RecyclerView and I would simply like for it to be replaced with a different Fragment. I'm just not sure which container to replace?

Here is the XML for my main Activity that has the ViewPager:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/main_header"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:title="@string/app_name">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        style="@style/AppTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/containerViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the XML for the Fragment with the RecyclerView:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/cocktailContainer"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragments.CocktailFragment">



<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/cocktail_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

And here is my code inside the Fragment's onClick method that should replace the current RecyclerView Fragment with a new new one:

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.cocktailContainer, new RecipesFragment() ).commit();
```

My issue is, I'm not sure what I should be replacing. From the current code above, the new Fragment pops up on top of the old one but the old one is still there (The word recipes is the new Fragment):

[image]

How do I get it to replace the RecyclerView completely? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the old fragment to be at the bottom, you can remove it from the back stack before adding the new fragment by calling remove method. 
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.cocktailContainer))